# Need to update a p tag every time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have this drum machine set up:

Every button triggers a click event (which plays an audio clip) and pressing a key of the same value as a button also triggers a key event (which plays the same audio clip AND writes inside the display tag).

How can I make the click events write inside the display tag as well?

```
<div id="drum-machine">
        <div id="display">
            <p id="displaytext"></p>
        </div>
            <div id="controls1">
            <button id="Heater1button" onclick="document.getElementById('Q').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id="Q" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>Q</button>
            <button id="Heater2button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='W' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>W</button>
            <button id="Heater3button" onclick="document.getElementById('E').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='E' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>E</button>
            </div>
        <div id="controls2">
            <button id="Heater4button" onclick="document.getElementById('A').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='A' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>A</button>
            <button id="Heater6button" onclick="document.getElementById('S').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='S'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"></audio>S</button>
            <button id="OpenHHbutton" onclick="document.getElementById('D').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='D'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"></audio>D</button>
        </div>
        <div id="controls3">
        <button id="KicknHat" onclick="document.getElementById('Z').play();" class="
        drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='Z'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"></audio>Z</button>
        <button id="Kickbutton"onclick="document.getElementById('X').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='X'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"></audio>X</button>
        <button id="ClosedHHbutton"onclick="document.getElementById('C').play();" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='C' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"></audio>C</button>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).keydown(function(e){
            switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 81: document.getElementById('Q').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Heater 1")
break;
                    case 87: document.getElementById('W').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Heater 2")
break;
                    case 69: document.getElementById('E').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Heater 3")
break;
                    case 65: document.getElementById('A').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Heater 4")
break;
                    case 83: document.getElementById('S').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Heater 6")
break;
                   case 68: document.getElementById('D').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Open HH")
break;

                   case 90: document.getElementById('Z').play(),$("#displaytext").text("KicknHat")
break;
                   case 88: document.getElementById('X').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Kick")
break;
                   case 67: document.getElementById('C').play(),$("#displaytext").text("Closed HH")
break;
}})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to declare the functions separately and use them in both places

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
function playQ() {
  $('#Q')[0].play();
  $('#displaytext').text('Heater 1');
}
</script>

<div id="drum-machine">
    <div id="display">
        <p id="displaytext"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="controls1">
        <button
            id="Heater1button"
            onclick="playQ()"
            class="drum-pad">
            Q
            <audio
                id="Q"
                class="clip"
                src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
                preload="auto"></audio>
        </button>
</div></div>



<script>
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 81:
      playQ();
      break;
}});
</script>
```

There can be more improvements, with less code.

Comment: @zer00ne you are absolutely right! Fixed. Thank you!
And your solution is undoubtedly better.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you. BTW I haven't been able to get any sound when playing any `<audio>` tags in SO Snippets, are you experiencing that as well?

Comment: @zer00ne If SO Snippet is the snippet right here, then yes. I've just edited my code a bit and now it actually plays. I even referenced jquery so it stopped barking at errors.

Comment: For me, both your answer and my answer play audio as if on mute, this only happens with code in SO Snippets for me. `$('#Q')[0]` is called dereferencing `$('#Q').get(0);` is the other way of dereferencing a jQuery Object into a DOM Object.

Comment: Yes, both your and mine code snippets produce music for me. Keyboard and html button ones. Don't know what can interfere. Browser plugins? Maybe something in console log?

Answer (score 2):

## Callback Function

A callback function is an anonymous or named function that is invoked once a registered event is triggered. The following demo features a callback function called `playMedia()` which will handle both `click` and `keyup` events from a `<button>` and the keyboard respectively.

BTW never use inline attribute event handlers -- also known as on-event handlers -- (ex. `<button ... onclick="func()"...>`) when jQuery is loaded, it's like using a paddle in a speedboat.  On-event handlers are harder to maintain, limited in scope and functionality compared to the power and versatility of jQuery methods.

---

### HTML

There are some semantical changes that are optional such as:

- each `<div>` that contained 3 `<buttons>` was changed into a `<fieldset>`
- the entire interface was wrapped in a `<fieldset>` and a `<form>`
- the `<p>` and the `<div>` wrapped around it were changed into an `<output>` and a `<legend>` respectively. An `<output>` will accept values from the `.value` (jQ: `.val()`) and the `.textContent` (jQ: `.text()`) properties.

The required changes are:

- each `<button>` `#id` is a pattern:

  - "b" and the *"shared letter"* -- ex. `<button id="bQ"...>`
- each `<audio>` `#id` is a pattern:

  - "a" and the *"shared letter"* -- ex. `<audio id="aQ"...>`
- each `<button>` has a custom attribute named: `data-txt` with a value that is displayed in `output#display`

  ---

### JavaScript/jQuery

There are various changes to leverage the `#ids` of the `<button>s` and `<audio>s` and the association between them. The details will be commented within the demo. If the `<audio>` tags run but there's no sound, try reviewing this **[functioning Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/bgII3ET5ExkGJGo1/)** instead.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**
**If the `<audio>` tags run but there's no sound, try reviewing this [functioning Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/bgII3ET5ExkGJGo1/) instead.**

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
    }
    
    fieldset {
      width: fit-content;
      padding: 15px
    }
    
    legend {
      font-size: 1.5rem
    }
    
    button {
      width: 5ch;
      text-align: center
    }
    
    output {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="drumMachine">

    <fieldset class='mainControl'>
      <legend>
        <output id="display">&nbsp;</output>
      </legend>

      <fieldset class="controls">

        <button id="bQ" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Heater 1">
    <audio class="clip" id="aQ" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>Q</button>

        <button id="bW" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Heater 2">
    <audio class="clip" id='aW' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>W</button>

        <button id="bE" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Heater 3">
    <audio class="clip" id='aE' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>E</button>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="controls">

        <button id="bA" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Heater 4">
    <audio class="clip" id='aA' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>A</button>

        <button id="bS" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Heater 5">
    <audio class="clip" id='aS'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"></audio>S</button>

        <button id="bD" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Open HH">
    <audio class="clip" id='aD'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"></audio>D</button>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="controls">
        <button id="bZ" class="drum-pad" data-txt="KicknHat">
    <audio class="clip" id='aZ'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"></audio>Z</button>

        <button id="bX" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Kick">
    <audio class="clip" id='aX'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"></audio>X</button>

        <button id="bC" class="drum-pad" data-txt="Closed HH">
    <audio class="clip" id='aC' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"></audio>C</button>

      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Callback function playMedia() handles both events
    $(document).on('keyup', playMedia);
    $('.drum-pad').on('click', playMedia);


    function playMedia(e) {
      /* 
      Prevent <form> from submitting data to a server when a <button>
      is clicked. This behavior can also be prevented by adding:
      type="button" to each <button> as well.
      */
      e.preventDefault();
      var letter, info;

      //  If the event.type is a click then...
      if (e.type === 'click') {
        // ...get the #id of the clicked node...
        var ID = e.target.id;
        // ...get the text in the clicked node's data-txt attribute
        info = e.target.dataset.txt;
        // Next split the text of the #id and keep the last letter
        letter = ID.split('').pop();
        // But if the event.type is a keyup...
      } else if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        /*
         ...get the keycode and run it through the switch() to
         get the letter associated with a <button>/<audio> pair.
         */
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 81:
            letter = "Q";
            break;
          case 87:
            letter = "W";
            break;
          case 69:
            letter = "E";
            break;
          case 65:
            letter = "A";
            break;
          case 83:
            letter = "S";
            break;
          case 68:
            letter = "D";
            break;
          case 90:
            letter = "Z";
            break;
          case 88:
            letter = "X";
            break;
          case 67:
            letter = "C";
            break;
        }
        /*
        Find the correct <button> and extract the text from its
        data-txt attribute
        */
        info = document.getElementById('b' + letter).dataset.txt;
      } else {
        // Otherwise end function
        return false;
      }
      // Find the correct <audio>
      var node = document.getElementById('a' + letter);
      // Play <audio>
      node.play();
      /*
      Set the value of output#display to the extracted text from
      data-txt 
      */
      document.getElementById('display').value = info;
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```